# Why aren't tornadoes embedded in squall lines or tornadoes in high-precipitation supercells destroyed by downdrafts?

Tags: meteorology, tornado

I often hear that tornadoes die when the RFD ([Rear Flank Downdraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rear_flank_downdraft)) strengthens and destroys their source of inflow... How do tornadoes get any inflowing updrafts when they are embedded in rain? How can they sustain themselves?

Comment: I do not work in tornadoes but from what i know of mesoscale systems i think the updraft is quite significant and it maybe greater than the RFD sustaining the tornado. Somebody who has worked in this area can provide numbers